# How to escape echo for input tag?

Tags: php, functions

How should I escape echo for this function...

```
function pen_post_sidebar_twitter() {
    $twitter = esc_attr( get_option( 'twitter_handler' ));
    echo ( '<input type="text" name="twitter_handler" value="'.$twitter.'" placeholder="Twitter handler" /> <p class="description">Enter twitter handler without the @ sign.</p>' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function pen_post_sidebar_twitter() {
    printf( '<input type="text" name="twitter_handler" value="%s" placeholder="Twitter handler" /> <p class="description">Enter twitter handler without the @ sign.</p>', esc_attr( get_option( 'twitter_handler' ) ) );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is correct, but you should explain what you did and why you did it.